# Azure Event Hub - Receiving events in batches C#

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

How do I read events in batches, let's say by batch of 50?
Azure function implements batch processing but Azure.Messaging.EventHubs Nuget doesn't provide that functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this depends on your scenario; if you'd prefer to read from a single partition and to have explicit control, the `PartitionReceiver` allows reading in batches.  [[sample]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample05_ReadingEvents.md#read-events-from-a-partition-using-the-partitionreceiver)

If you're looking to work with an event processor type that handles load balancing, checkpointing, and resiliency, the`EventProcessor<T>`offers the extension point for batch-based processing as well as other customization and control. [[sample]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample08_CustomEventProcessor.md)